# Redirect directory to new domain without touching the main site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect https://mineyourmind.de/forum to https://mineyourmind.net/forum .

Every rewrite rule I could google didn´t work, they also redirected the main domain (mineyourmind.de).

Im redirecting http:// www. and http:// and https:// via the apache siteconfig.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mineoyurmind\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://mienoyurmind.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The .htaccess of the forum directory looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /xenforo

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Should I add the rewrite for mineyourmind.de/forum to mineyourmind.net/forum to the apache site config or to the htaccess and how should this look like ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only redirect `/forum` then you want to add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mineoyurmind\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*) https://mienoyurmind.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And add it to your htaccess file right below `RewriteEngine On`.